# Can I generate a "fully exposed" and "normal" version of Haddock docs without recompiling?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock

I am using Haddock (w/ Stack) to generate documentation for a software suite I'm working on. I would like to generate 2 variants of the Haddock docs; one normally (e.g., vanilla `stack haddock`), and one with fully exposed modules (e.g., `stack haddock --haddock-arguments "--show-all"`). However, I've found that I needed to run `stack clean` in-between haddock generation, or else the second command that I run would not generate anything. We would like to try to avoid this `stack clean` (which results in needing a recompilation of the entire software suite).

Expected steps (not working):

1. `stack haddock`
2. ... copy over the docs to our local folders for public posting ...
3. `stack haddock --haddock-arguments "--show-all"`
4. ... copy over the fully exposed docs to our local folders for public posting ...

The problem here with the above steps is that the second `stack haddock` will just default to using the haddock docs that were already built, ignoring the `"--show-all"` change. We can fix this by adding a `stack clean` in-between runs:

Working steps:

1. `stack haddock`
2. ... copy over the docs to our local folders for public posting ...
3. `stack clean`
4. `stack haddock --haddock-arguments "--show-all"`
5. ... copy over the fully exposed docs to our local folders for public posting ...

However, adding this `stack clean` step results in an extra recompilation of the entire software suite for step 4. Is there anyway that I can get around needing this step? I've already tried to manually delete the `$(stack path --local-install-root)/doc` folder before the second docs generation, but this didn't work without a full clean.

My Stack version is `Version 2.7.3, Git revision 7927a3aec32e2b2e5e4fb5be76d0d50eddcc197f x86_64 hpack-0.34.4`.